# magento : product options in product page

Tags: magento

i m a beginner in magento and i have a product page as described in image bellow :

[image]

so the i wanna show red area like the brown one in the image bellow :

[image]

how to do that in admin if its possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Souf,goto view.phtml (app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/template/catalog/product/)here find code

```
 <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
```

just up the corroding to your wished place in view.phtml

Comment: and in admin is it possible ? @AmitBera